# How to apply class methods to my own class' property in Python

Tags: python, methods, properties, pygame

I created a class called `Thing` for Pygame, which will later be subclassed to develop more specific classes and objects. This class needs to store among other attributes, the **position**, and **size** of the object.

However, Pygame has this very powerful class called `Rect` that can already do that, and has many useful built-in methods and properties. I *could* use a single `Rect` attribute in my `Thing` class, but it stores position in integers, and I'm looking to store it in floats (a `Thing` might need to move less than one pixel per frame).

This I what I had in mind.

```py
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, pos, size):
        self.x: float = pos[0]
        self.y: float = pos[1]
        self.size = size

    @property
    def rect(self):
        return pygame.Rect((self.x, self.y), self.size)

    @rect.setter
    def rect(self, var: pygame.Rect):
        self.x = var.x
        self.y = var.y
        self.size = var.size
```

This would allow me to get and set the `Thing`'s `Rect`, but I wouldn't be able to use the `Rect`'s built-in setters as desired:

```py
foo = Thing((10, 10), (20, 20))
foo.draw(win)

foo.x += 100
foo.draw(win)

# This has no effect
foo.rect.y += 100
foo.draw(win)

temp = foo.rect
temp.x -= 100
foo.rect = temp
foo.draw(win)
```

[image: Actual Behavior]

The desired behavior for the above code would be to have the square move right, *down*, then left.

Is there a way to either:

- Have a `Rect` as a `Thing` attribute, but update `x` and `y` whenever it's changed?
- Apply methods to `Rect` property
- Some other solution you can think of

TL;DR: If I have a `Rect` as a property, I can't do `self.rect.center = (500,500)`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your property is a bit odd in that it returns a new instance of `Rect` each time  you access it, rather than returning an *existing* part of your `Thing`.

Comment: Yes! That's because I have to keep track of `x` and `y` separately in order to store position in floats. But I also want to use `Rect` methods to detect collisions, get and set center coordinates, etc.

Comment: @SamuelCabrera If you only need the center coordinates, then create a `center` property, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class should inherit from `pygame.Rect`. That is the only way to get the `Rect` methods automatically. However by doing this you will inherits also the `int` typecasting of the coordinates since that is in the original implementation of `pygame.Rect`. I'm afraid inheritance won't solve your problem.

You know what the `Rect` methods are supposed to do (The [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is well written), so I'm afraid the only way is to reimplement them (or at least reimplement those you need) for your own `Thing` class, to mimic the `Rect` behaviour with float numbers.

I did something similar: here is a portion of the class I wrote (I won't show it all because is too long) to give you an idea:

```
class FlRect:
    """Similar to pygame.Rect but uses float numbers.

    The class stores internally only coordinates, width and height.
    Other attributes are rendered through properties, with getter and setter:
    x, y: coordinates of the top-left corner of the rectangle.
    top, bottom: y coordinates of the top and bottom edges respectively.
    left, right: x coordinates of the left and right edges respectively.
    centerx, centery: coordinates of the centre of the rectangle.
    width, height: self-explanatory. 
    """

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        """Initialization:

        x, y - coordinates of top-left corner of the rectangle
        w, h - width and height
        """
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._w = w
        self._h = h

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self._w

    @width.setter
    def width(self, value):
        self._w = value

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self._h

    @height.setter
    def height(self, value):
        self._h = value

    @property
    def top(self):
        return self._y

    @top.setter
    def top(self, value):
        self._y = value

    @property
    def bottom(self):
        return self._y + self._h

    @bottom.setter
    def bottom(self, value):
        self._y = value - self._h

    @property
    def left(self):
        return self._x

    @left.setter
    def left(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self._x + self._w

    @right.setter
    def right(self, value):
        self._x = value - self._w

    @property
    def centerx(self):
        return self._x + (self._w / 2)

    @centerx.setter
    def centerx(self, value):
        self._x = value - (self._w / 2)

    @property
    def centery(self):
        return self._y + (self._h / 2)

    @centery.setter
    def centery(self, value):
        self._h = value - (self._h / 2)

    def get_rect(self):
        """Return a pygame.Rect object with rounded coordinates"""
        return Rect(round(self._x), round(self._y), round(self._w), round(self._h))
```

Of course this is not going to be as efficient as `pygame.Rect`, since this is written in python and the pygame Rect class is in C.

Comment: Thank you! I was afraid **I** might have to do something like this, but wasn´t sure how. Now you just did it for me. Again, thanks!